# reading xml use linq can't get all node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i'm new here, and my English not good, so this is my problem
[image]

so, it just show name, gender and first image. 
how to get all image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Share your code as a plain text. And please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Welcome to SO :). Please try to place all the relevant material inside your question, because it's difficult to go back and forth and check what we have, what's the question etc. So please copy and paste all the things you have included in your image inside your post. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Descendants()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get your `info` elements and (I assume) [FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.100).aspx) method to get a single picture:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"details.xml");
var obj = (from info in xml.Descendants("info")
            let name = info.Element("name").Value
            let picture = info.Descendants("image").FirstOrDefault()
            where name == value
            select new detail
            {
                Name = name,
                Gender = info.Element("gender").Value,
                Image = picture != null? picture.Value : null
            }).ToList();
```

*Edit 1*

To get all the images you need to make the following changes:

In class `detail` change the type of `Image` property

```
public IEnumerable<string> Images{ get; set; }
```

In the code that loads the data the following:

```
var obj = ( from info in xml.Descendants("info")
            let name = info.Element("name").Value
            let images = info.Descendants("image")
            where name == value
            select new detail
            {
                Name = name,
                Gender = info.Element("gender").Value,
                Images = images.Select(elem => elem.Value)
            }).ToList();
```

Last but not least, change the xaml to display a collection of images and bind it to the `Images` property of `detail` class.

*Edit 2*

To have a collection of images displayed in the xaml change the `Image` tag with the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource = {Binding Images}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <Image Source = {Binding .}></Image>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I haven't tested it so it may need some adjustments to work properly but this should be enough to point you the right direction.

**Happy New Year!**

Comment: thank for answered me, but just show first image. How to get all image

Comment: @abcd1234, sorry for late comment I was AFK. Please see the latest edit.

Comment: @ RePierre - i follow you, but image don't show. And i don't understand "change the xaml to display a collection of images and bind it to the Images property of detail class".thank for your help

Comment: @abcd1234, your xaml binds the string from Image property to the path of the image to display. Since the property will be transformed into a collection of strings you need to adjust the markup to display multiple images each having its Source bound to a value from the collection.

Comment: @ RePierre - thank you. but you can show me with code ? i don't know how to do that

Comment: @abcd1234, again sorry for late response and please see the latest edit.